# Why must the type in a linked-list data structure using references have the static lifetime?

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

When implementing a linked-list data structure using references, I came across the following situation:

```
pub struct Node<'a, T> {
    parent: Option<&'a Node<'a, T>>,
    data: T
}
```

This struct cannot be instantiated when using the `'static` lifetime for `'a` and a type `T` with non-`'static` lifetime. For example, consider the struct ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ec33ab48914d9cd71ff9db45cf7e367)):

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: Node<'static, &'a i32>
}
```

Including this results in the compiler error:

```
error[E0477]: the type `&'a i32` does not fulfill the required lifetime
 --> src\main.rs:9:10
  |
9 |     bar: Node<'static, &'a i32>
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: type must satisfy the static lifetime
```

Why does `T` have to have the `'static` lifetime here?

Comment: You've stated that all `Node`s have a reference with a lifetime and contain more references of the same lifetime. Why do you expect that you can then declare them to be different?

Comment: @Shepmaster Sorry, you are completely right, of course. I was so focused on the case `parent == None` (where it would make some sense) that I did not notice that the existence of a parent with lifetime `'static` already forces `T` to be static.